# Qual a diferença entre GetKeyState() e GetAsyncKeyState()?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, winapi

Sempre utilizei o `GetKeyState()` para saber se o usuário está pressionando uma tecla, mas vejo que muitas pessoas utilizam mais o `GetAsyncKeyState()`. Com isso me surgiu as seguintes duvidas:

1. Qual a diferença entre os 2?
2. Quando devo utilizar cada?
3. Em uma aplicação que devo ter o melhor desempenho e rapidez possível, qual devo utilizar?

Comment: Uma detecta o pressionamento e interrompe a execução, a outra continua a execução do thread atual de forma assíncrona. Na teoria, todas funções que tenham `Async` no nome, devem retornar uma `Task` assíncrona.

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente tem a ver com o **retorno** do método, na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) existe uma explicação específica: *"The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the GetAsyncKeyState function to retrieve that information."*

Saber qual deve utilizar depende do resultado que você deseja obter, já que os métodos retornam informações diferentes.

Comment: é interessante sempre traduzir citações/explicações para o português, não são todos que entendem ingles, mesmo trabalhando/estudando com isso

Comment: Só citei a parte em que a documentação refere-se á pergunta, para que ele encontre mais facilmente.